# CSS Table layout. Good way to accomplish this

Tags: html, css

I always wondering how can i take css seriously. I'm a very clean developer but my css seems to smell.
Just want to create the layout the extending thing will be made with javascript. Can somebody show me a solution in css how this can be accomplished. Forget the gradients and text color etc. Maybe need somebody in the future that will take this work for some credits.

[image]

```
<div class="FAQ">
    <div class="FAQ-Header">
        <div class="Help-Title-Label">Questions and Answers</div>
    </div>
    <div class="FAQ-Entry">
        <div class="FAQ-Question">
            <div class="FAQ-Question-Left">
                <div class="FAQ-Question-State">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="FAQ-Question-Right">
                <div class="FAQ-Question-Txt">My Question Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="FAQ-Answer">
            <div class="FAQ-Answer-Left">
                <div class="FAQ-Answer-Title">A:</div>
            </div>
            <div class="FAQ-Answer-Right">
                <div class="FAQ-Answer-Txt">My Question Answer.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="FAQ-Footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't even post `<table>` tags HTML so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: No, it can't. The whole point of tables is so you have columns that line and data cells that are machine readable for disabled people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I agree with vikingben.  Try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

If you do need to make your own accordion I recommend using a table for your HTML:

```
<table class="faq">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Questions and Answers</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>-</th><td>My Question Text</td></tr>
        <tr class="selected"><th>A:</th><td>My Question Answer.</td></tr>
        <tr><th>+</th><td>My Question Text</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You are modeling tabular data here and a table is a fine construct for modeling tabular data.  If you use a table the CSS will be trivially easy.  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/treyh/eGbA4/).

If you are concerned that you'll need to change the format later, restructure at that point.  You shouldn't fret over a future HTML tag refactor unless you think it's likely to happen and the effort spent upfront to avoid it is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recreate the wheel just use the JqueryUI accordion. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ takes the css out of the picture and adds the implementation in one step.

Comment: alternatively, use boostrap collapse http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse